# How to plot a schematic plot containing arbitrary smooth curves?

Tags: plotting

How can I make a plot similar to the one below (enthalpy vs T plot) in Mathematica?

[image: desired plot of phase transition]

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do you have expressions for those curves?

Comment: @MarcoB No, I don't. The curves are just schematics. So, anything that resembles that should work. The only thing to notice is that  the curves are linear in the glass and liquid regions, as you can see by the dotted lines and there is only a region in between which is not linear. I am not sure how to do that part in Mathematica to resemble that figure.

Comment: What have you tried? Which part are you having difficulty?

Comment: @xzczd I can do exactly the same plot but completely linear (without the non linear region). I am not sure how to reproduce that region in mathematica.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to link 2 straight lines with a smooth curve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is in generating a [`BezierCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve.html) or some such construct. Here is a version built by hand, just because this was more fun than the actual work I had to do right now :-)

```
blue = RGBColor[0.3, 0.45, 1]
green = RGBColor[0.25, 0.35, 0.15];

Show[{
  Plot[Style[4 x - 2, Black, Dashed], {x, 0.5, 4}],
  Plot[Style[1/2 x + 4, Black, Dashed], {x, 0, 2.5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Dashed],
  Plot[Style[1/2 x + 1, Black, Dashed], {x, -1, 1.5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Dashed],
  Graphics[{
    blue, Thickness[0.01],
    Arrowheads[{{0.06, 0.3}, {0.06, 0.95}}],
    Arrow@BezierCurve[{{4, 14}, {2, 5.9}, {1.8, 4.8}, {0, 4}}]
    }],
  Graphics[{
    green, Thickness[0.01],
    Arrowheads[{{0.06, 0.97}}],
    Arrow@BezierCurve[{{4, 14}, {0.8, 1}, {0.9, 1.3}, {-1, 0.5}}]
    }],
  Graphics[{
    Inset[Style["Glass", 24], {0.8, 7}],
    Inset[Style["Liquid", 24], {2.7, 12}],
    blue, 
    Inset[Style[StandardForm@"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(1\)]\)", 
      24], {0.5, 5.2}],
    green, 
    Inset[Style[StandardForm@"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \(2\)]\)", 
      24], {-0.7, 1.5}]
   }]
 },
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> {"T", "V, H"},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 24, Thickness[0.01]],
 FrameTicks -> {
   {None, None},
   {
    {
     {12/7, 
      Style[StandardForm@"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(g1\)]\)", blue, 
       Bold],
      {0.03, 0}, Thickness[0.01]},
     {6/7, 
      Style[StandardForm@"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(g2\)]\)", green,
        Bold],
      {0.03, 0}, Thickness[0.01]}},
    None
   }
  },
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 4.5}, {-2, 15}},
 AspectRatio -> 0.8, ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image: result of code above, resembling desired plot]

Comment: MarcoB thank you very much! This is such an amazing code! I really appreciate it !

Comment: @John You're very welcome. I was quite bored with whatever I was doing at the time. It was a nice diversion :-)

Comment: MarcoB, if you happen to be bored again I would appreciate if you can help me with this slightly more difficult problem that I just posted: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234958/solve-complex-equation-in-mathematica

Answer (score 1):

Using a slightly modified version of input data from MarcoB's answer we construct two `BezierFunction`s. With parametric functions finding the tangent line to a curve at a point and placing text labels becomes convenient:

```
bf1 = BezierFunction[{{4, 14}, {2, 5.9}, {1.8, 4.8}, {-1, 4}}];
bf2 = BezierFunction[{{4, 14}, {0.9, 1.3}, {0.5, 1.}, {-1, 0.5}}];
blue = RGBColor[0.3, 0.45, 1];
green = RGBColor[0.25, 0.35, 0.15];

prolog = {Text[Style[Subscript[q, 2], 16, blue], Offset[{0, 15}, bf1[.9]]],
      Text[Style[Subscript[q, 1], 16, green], Offset[{0, 15}, bf2[.85]]],
      Text[Style["Glass", 16, Gray], Offset[{-20, 20}, bf1[.2]]],
      Text[Style["Liquid", 16, Gray], Offset[{-20, 40}, bf1[.8]]],
      Dashed, InfiniteLine[bf1[.2], bf1'[.2]], 
      InfiniteLine[bf1[.9], bf1'[.9]], 
      InfiniteLine[bf2[.9], bf2'[.9]]};


Show[ParametricPlot[{bf1[t], bf2[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> Thread[{AbsoluteThickness[4], 
        {Arrowheads[{{.04, .75}, {0.04, .9}}], Arrowheads[{{.04, .2}, {.04, .75},
        {0.04, .95}}]}, {blue, green}}], 
      AspectRatio -> 2/3, Frame -> True, 
      FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {MapThread[{#, Style[##2]} &,
         {{12, 6}/7, Subscript[T, #] & /@ {g1, g2} , {blue, green}}], None}}, 
      FrameLabel -> {{"V, H", None}, {"T", None}}, LabelStyle -> 16, 
      FrameStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False] /. Line -> Arrow, 
  Prolog -> prolog, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Two arbitrary parametric curves:

```
SeedRandom[123]
bf1 = BezierFunction[Reverse@SortBy[First]@RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {15, 2}]];
bf2 = {Cos[2 Pi #] , Sin[2Pi (1-#)]/#}&;

Show[ParametricPlot[{bf1[t], bf2[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> Thread[{AbsoluteThickness[4], 
        {Arrowheads[{{.04, .75}, {0.04, .9}}], 
          Arrowheads[{{.04, .2}, {.04, .65}, {0.04, .9}}]}, 
         {blue, green}}],
      AspectRatio -> 2/3, Frame -> True, 
      FrameTicks -> None, FrameStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False] /. 
    Line -> Arrow, 
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], 
      Text[Style[Subscript[q, 2], 16, blue], Offset[{-15, 15}, bf1[.5]]],
      Text[Style[Subscript[q, 1], 16, green], Offset[{15, 15}, bf2[.2]]],
      Dashed, Orange, InfiniteLine[bf1[.2], bf1'[.2]], Point[bf1[.2]], 
      Cyan, InfiniteLine[bf1[.5], bf1'[.5]], Point[bf1[.5]],
      Magenta, InfiniteLine[bf2[.38], bf2'[.38]], Point[bf2[.38]]},
     ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]